# Verify Brownian motion stochastic integral identity only using definition

Tags: stochastic-integrals

I have to verify, using only the definition of stochastic integral, that:
$$
(B \cdot B)_t := \int_0^t B_s \text{d}B_s = \frac{1}{2} B_t^2 - \frac{1}{2}t.
$$

Below what I've tried so far.

Given $M \in H^2$, $K \in L^2(M)$ the *stochastic integral* $K \cdot M$ is the only process such that:
$$
\left< K \cdot M, N \right> = K \cdot \left< M, N \right> \quad \forall N \text{ martingale in } H^2.
$$

Let $Y_t = \frac{1}{2} B_t^2 - \frac{1}{2}t$. By definition of stochastic integral I have to verify that
$$
\left< B \cdot B, N \right> = B \cdot \left<B,N \right> \quad \forall N \in H^2
$$
namely
$$
\left<Y,N \right> = B \cdot \left<B,N \right>.
$$
Letting $Z_t = t$ it is equivalent to show that:
$$
\left<\frac{1}{2} B^2,N \right> + \left<\frac{1}{2} Z,N \right>
= B \cdot \left<B,N \right>
$$
by bilinearity of covariation.
Given the fact that $Z$ is a finite variation process (because it is continuous and increasing) I get
$$
\left<\frac{1}{2} Z, N \right> = 0.
$$
But now I'm stuck because I don't understand how to further manipulate $\left<B^2,N \right>$.

Any hint would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My favourite proof is this:
\begin{align}
&\int_0^tB_s\,dB_s=\lim_{n\to\infty\atop\Pi_n\to 0}\sum_{i=1}^nB_{t_i}(B_{t_{i+1}}-B_{t_i})\\
&=\frac{1}{2}\lim_{n\to\infty\atop\Pi_n\to 0}\sum_{i=1}^n(B_{t_i}-B_{t_{i+1}}+B_{t_{i+1}}+B_{t_i})(B_{t_{i+1}}-B_{t_i})\\
&=-\frac{1}{2}\underbrace{\lim_{n\to\infty\atop\Pi_n\to 0}\sum_{i=1}^n(B_{t_{i+1}}-B_{t_i})(B_{t_{i+1}}-B_{t_i})}_{\textstyle\langle B\rangle_t=t}+\frac{1}{2}\underbrace{\lim_{n\to\infty\atop\Pi_n\to 0}\sum_{i=1}^n(B^2_{t_{i+1}}-B^2_{t_i})}_{\textstyle B_t^2}\,
\end{align}
where $\Pi_n=\max\limits_{i=1,...,n}|t_{i+1}-t_i|$ and the last simplifcation to $B_t^2$ is due to the sum being telescoping.